# Unexpected nil check results for optional value in dictionary

Tags: swift, cocoa

I have noticed a behaviour that I find confusing when checking if a value in a dictionary is a nil. In the notification handler for a certain notification, I want to check if the value for the error key is nil. While trying to debug this I tried the following:

> po userInfo["error"]
>
> ▿ Optional
>    - some : nil
>
> (lldb) po userInfo["error"] == nil
>
> false

Given the output for the first command, I expected the second to return true. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: I think it's not nil. But to confirm, could you check what is the output of `po userInfo["error"]!` . (force unwrap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the culprit. I was creating the dictionary as follows:

`let userInfo = [DatabaseRestaurantNotificationPayload.infoDictionaryErrorKe‌​y:nil, DatabaseRestaurantNotificationPayload.infoDictionaryRestaura‌​ntKey:value1] as [String : Any]`

and unlike what one might expect this ends up actually adding an optional for the error key, so that querying the dictionary for the errorKey returns Optional(nil) rather than nil itself.

Answer (score 2):

`userInfo["error"]` is giving back `Optional<Sometype>.some(Optional<SomeOtherType>.none)`. So the `userInfo` dictionary **does** have a value for the key `"error"`, but that value is another Optional, which itself is `nil`.

Here's a code snippet that mimics the structure:

```
let userInfo: [String: String?] = [
    "something": "something else",
    "another thing": "yet another thing",
    "error": nil
]

print(userInfo["error"] as Any) // Optional(nil)
```

Comment: Hey Alex, do you have to cast it as Any when printing it? I assume that it should be `nil` by default.

Comment: @AhmadF It's not necessary, but the Swift compiler warns you when you try to coerce `Any?` into `Any`, which is usually a code smell. What `default` are you talking about?

Comment: I mean without the need of casting it to `Any` the result should be "Optional(nil)", but as you mentioned, the compiler will shoot a warning...

Comment: @AhmadF Yeah, as I said, it's not necessary. It's [syntactic salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar#Syntactic_salt), used to verify that you really mean for the coercion from `Any?` to `Any` to happen, and not by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You know that Any can contain anything, right? It can also contain an optional. And it can contain an optional that is nil.

It looks like this is what is happening here. userInfo ["error"] isn't nil, it contains an optional with a value of nil. That's not the same thing. I'd check how you created that userInfo.